# Error during solidity smart contract deployment : Uncaught Error: Callback was already called

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ganache

Uncaught Error: Callback was already called.
at /home/blockchain/master/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:43:36
at WriteStream. (node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:358:17)
at WriteStream.destroy (node_modules/level-ws/level-ws.js:140:8)
at finish (internal/streams/writable.js:670:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:434:9)

Answer (score 3):

Found out this to be a problem with node v14.x and ganache-cli v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2).

Installing node v13.9.0 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, reinstalling ganache-cli fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [latest version 7.0.3](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#documentation) of `ganache` instead `ganache-cli`

```
npm install --save-dev ganache
```

in code just use

```
const ganache = require('ganache');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
```